# Learning to do proofs: Examples or theory

Tags: soft-question, proof-theory

So I have a couple of weeks to study what I want before heading back to college. I am debating whether to study multivariable calculus or to study how to write proofs in general.

For context, I have already taken two proof based courses: A bit of real analysis and proof-based linear algebra. I did rather poorly in real analysis, and I attribute this to the fact that I did not have a lot of experience writing analysis proofs beforehand. Even now though I don't feel that I can write great real analysis proofs. In contrast, I did rather well in linear algebra, and felt I understood it decently well with a bit of preparation. However, I found that a non-insignificant number of times during linear algebra I wrote down a proof that I convinced myself was good, and there was some issue that made it a false proof.

I hope it's clear how it can be confusing as to what I should study. It seems that I did well in linear algebra by looking at examples of proofs, but neither before nor after this practice do I feel comfortable with real analysis, and there are also clear weak spots that I have. I'm not sure which way to approach learning proofs.

My own personal question is what is appropriate to study in order to get better at writing proofs, multivariable calculus proofs, real analysis proofs, or reading a book that generally aids with proofs? To make this question more general so that it is appropriate for this medium, I guess I would ask, what is better for learning proofs thoroughly after some exposure - seeing examples of proofs and trying your own, or reading a book for teaching proofs and trying your own? The book I've had in mind while writing this is Bridge to Abstract Mathematics by Morash.

I hope this is appropriate to ask here. I don't know what better place to get this advice from than math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: My opinion is that you can start with a real analysis book because others topics are more advanced and probably the proofs are not shown in the same level of detail. To understand how to prove something you need examples and practice, there are different general strategies to prove something depending of the topic you are studying. In this way you can try to complete the book *Understanding analysis* of Abbott.

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't know where to start with books to read. But keep in mind that we've all made mistakes in our process of learning to do formal logic. it just takes practice. As for analysis in general I suggest reading a good analysis book that makes sense for you.

Comment: There is one helpful suggestion I would make in terms of analytical proofs. When ever possible play the $\varepsilon$ game, or the $\varepsilon,\; \delta$ game. When you get used to them they can be quite fun to do, though a bit tedious.

Comment: The best way to learn to write proofs is to try writing them then get feedback / criticism / suggestions from people who are good at proofs. Maybe there should be a stackexchange site specifically for that, analogous to the code review stackexchange site. Or maybe you can post your attempted proofs here on math.stackexchange with a question like, "Is this proof correct?"

Comment: @Sentinel135 A lot of the very difficult stuff for me involved least upper bounds and set comparisons in real analysis. I don't think I remember limits being my biggest worries (although they were certainly worries). I'm not sure if the $\epsilon$ game would apply there.

Comment: @Masacroso Ok, so your argument is real analysis will give me the best idea of how to write proofs (while other topics won't go into as much detail and will have important concepts glossed over)?

Comment: I dont know if real analysis is *the best place* to start *for you* but Im sure that it is a good place (in general) to start learning how to prove things. Anyway you can try with other topics were you are more interested than real analysis (by example combinatorics, probability, set theory, logic, linear or abstract algebra... whatever). Just try and you will see by yourself.

Comment: @KennyDuran Okay, Question: Given the set $A:=\{x\in \mathbb R: x\in [0,1)\}$ What is the 1) greatest lower bound; 2) the lowest upper bound; 3) the greatest upper bound, and 4) the lowest lower bound? How would you prove that they exist or not?

Comment: Terrence Tao's analysis book starts from very basic proofs using the Peano axioms and works its way up. He claims in the foreword that it really helped his students get a handle on proofs. I remember back in real analysis wondering what the heck when we were supposed to prove 1+1=2, but having gone back and looked at it I found it very useful.

Comment: @Sentinel135 Give me about 15 minutes to refresh on how these proofs have been done before. I'll give you my first thoughts before reviewing for a moment. My first thought for 1) was honestly just to cite that the interval x is defined to be in is closed from below, and so the glb takes on the value of the element x is defined to be greater than or equal to. I might prove that separately. I would not know how to prove existence well tbh.

Comment: you might find reading my book "proof patterns" useful. It attempts to give you a toolkit across areas for many of the proofs you will encounter.

Comment: @Sentinel135 For 2) I might say that since $0 \leq x < 1$ then $t_n(x) < t_n(1) \leq 1$ for all $x \in A$ and $n\in N$, so there exists an upper bound of 1. I wouldn't know what to do to show that it is the least upper bound offhand. Intuitively my thoughts would go to make some set of upper bounds and show that something less than 1 can't be in this set.
3) The gub... I guess I would say that any set with an upper bound has no greatest upper bound?
4) The llb would have the same principle as 3, in that any set with a lower bound (which, if I knew how to show 1, we have shown) has no llb.

Comment: @KennyDuran you're on the right track. 1 is the lowest upper bound. You can prove it's existence by noting that $x<1$ for all $x \in A$. You then need to prove that it is the lowest one. So suppose it isn't...

Comment: @KennyDuran yes for the gub and the llb you need to show that the sets are unbounded. That takes a little finagling by that I mean making a subset of the set that's well ordered. BTW this is where you play the epsilon game.

Comment: @Sentinel135 Suppose that 1 is not the l.u.b. of A.Then there exists a y such that $y < 1$ and $x < y$ for $\forall x \in A$. But if $y < 1$, then we have that either $y \in [0, 1)$ or $y \in (-\infty, 0)$. If $y \in (-\infty, 0)$, then y is not greater than all $x \in A$, i.e. $.5$. If $y \in [0, 1)$, then $y \in A$. But we have that $x < y$ for all $x \in A$, so $y < y \in A$, a contradiction. Thus we cannot have that there exists some upper bound less than 1, so 1 is the lub.
Thanks for that. I think this was probably just an easier example and I would get tripped up a lot on these though.

Comment: @Sentinel135 So, I'll try to come up with that well ordering proof you mention. I'm trying to get it out of my head that it's obvious that if there exists an upper bound then there does not exist a greatest upper bound. One moment :)

Comment: @Sentinel135 So... I have a question before I proceed with the epsilon game. Why could I not say for the gub that 1 is a lub, $1<2, 2<3, 3<4, etc.$ and so for all y in the set $\mathbb{N} - {1}$ that $y > x \in A$ and so there is a <--- I go in wrong directions like this all the time. Like, my intuitive thoughts went to there is an ordered set of natural numbered elements that are greater than 1, there is no ub for the natural numbers, so there is no greatest upper bound.

Comment: @Sentinel135 I really appreciate you taking time out to help me with this. I know this won't last much longer, so may I ask what resource could help me, to the best of your knowledge, as you have helped me now? I can get my hands on "The Way of Analysis" by Strichartz or probably any other sort of resource like this to make it happen. Thanks so much for being so helpful.

Comment: @kenny yes you can use an induction proof to show that the there is no gub, and likewise an llb. There's nothing wrong with that. It's just you have to be careful because you are dealing with a subset of the natural number and likewise a subset of the integers, and not all subsets are unbounded. As for other knowledge I can only suggest asking questions; talking to other mathematicians; and read books that you find interesting that use proofs. You are always welcome to ask questions here, even though some might downgrade them.  I'll try to keep an eye out for any questions you post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should study multivariable calculus. Learning to write proofs is not something you can do without relevant statements to prove, or at least it's a quite hard thing to do.

I would also recommend that you diversify your math courses. Proofs in different sub disciplines look a bit different and will improve your repertoire. Also different teachers will have different styles which will help you finally get it.

Also depth is useful in order to learn proving things. The proofs that you do in single-variable calculus are often special cases (because the theorems are) of proofs that you do in multi-variable calculus and beyond. This means some repetition (with variations) that is also beneficial. This is also a good thing because if you really didn't get it the first time you will when you get it have proven something more general and not actually need to prove the special case from single-variable calculus.